# Searching datas with LIKE on result of CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to use LIKE sql syntax to filter the results of my DB outputs. Firstly I retrieve data that I want using with CASE and WHEN coditions. Like as below...

```
            , CASE
            WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 1 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION1
            WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 2 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION2
            WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION3
            END AS item
```

And then , I want to check with LIKE syntax over this outcomes.

```
        WHERE  ACC.RECORD_DEL_FLG = 0
               AND item LIKE '%%'
```

There have been thrown MYSQL Exception.. Unknown Column 'item'. My question is how to do that ? Thanks in advances to everybody. Please help me how to figure out.

Comment: Can we see the entire query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use the `ALIAS` that is created on the same level of the `WHERE` clause. You hvae two choices,

One, to wrap it in a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ....,
          CASE
            WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 1 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION1
            WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 2 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION2
            WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION3
            END item
   FROM tableName
) x
WHERE x.Item LIKE '%%'
```

Second, use the whole expression on the `WHERE` clause,

```
WHERE ACC.RECORD_DEL_FLG = 0 AND 
      CASE WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 1 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION1
           WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 2 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION2
           WHEN ACC.ACCOUNT_TYPE = 3 THEN BNK.DESCRIPTION3
      END LIKE '%%'
```

The reason why you cannot use `ALIAS` is because in the `SQL Order of Operation`, the `WHERE` clause executes before `SELECT` clause. Here's the list `SQL Order of Operation`:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause